# Can you use TCL (Expect) to script operations on a Progress Character UI legacy app on Solaris?

Tags: tcl, expect, progress-4gl, chui

The title says it all, really.

On a Sun OS 5.1, can I automate some operations on a legacy Progress (ported to v.10, but still running as a character based UI, launched by Procedure Editor) using [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)?

Anyone had any real experience with this setup? Is it known to work? Or not to work at all? Any caveats?

Comment: If the UI is build with ansi-escape code, you can automate it, although it is not easy.

Comment: If you're using the procedure editor, then I presume you've got the code, in which case it'd be possible to setup a batch program to do what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, we have access to the code, lots of code where business logic is buried inside on-screen controls, specifically, so while we plan to rewrite that part I want to evaluate short-term workarounds.

Comment: @TimKuehn - that's what I am trying to find out: what does Progress use (on Solaris) to manage character-based interfaces? Curses? Something else? Can it be managed by TCL?

Comment: @Charles - ABL (Advaced Business Language - formerly 4GL) is the language used for writing Progress applications (sorta like you would say PL-SQL was used for Oracle SQL*Forms apps). Removing it is no big deal, anyway.

Comment: Aha!  There's already a tag for that language.  Tada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I've done it.

It was quite a while ago but it is certainly possible.

No special caveats specifically due to Progress.  It was challenging to automatically navigate through a complex application -- but you would expect that (pun intended...)

As I recall the hardest part was coming up with distinct "anchor" strings for each screen.

It was also useful to build in a bit of wait time here and there.

Comment: Yep, we already use "macros" i.e. keypresses sent directly to the terminal emulator, and we can add waits there, but we can't test for specific output, so if something goes amiss, we keep sending stuff with the risk of making blind moves. I'd like to use expect to limit the risk. Thanks...